# JavaFX - Passing informating from the controller of a popup to the invoking controller

Tags: java, javafx

I've been trying to get something to work for some time now, but it's not getting along. I'm relatively new to GUIs and am trying this in JavaFX, using IntelliJ and the Gluon SceneBuilder. This is what I want to do:

When I click a `Button` on my original window, a popup appears. This is essentially a new window, if this is unusual please let me know. In this popup, there are three `TextField`s in which I can enter stuff. When I click a "Confirm" `Button` on the popup, the popup must close and tell the controller which invoked it the things that were entered in the `TextField`s.

I hope I've provided enough information. I've been searching all day and asked some more seasoned programmers, but to no avail.

Right now, this is the relative code (excuse the Dutch):

**Base controller**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

    public Controller(){
        people = new ArrayList<>();
        casks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void startNewCask(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/NewCask.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("New cask");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**Controller of popup**

```
public class NewCaskController {
    @FXML
    private TextField price;
    @FXML
    private TextField volume;
    @FXML
    private TextField type;
    @FXML
    private Button confirm;

    @FXML
    public void handleConfirm(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) confirm.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
```

**JavaFX of the popup**

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="305.0" maxWidth="260.0" minHeight="230.0" minWidth="260.0" prefHeight="246.0" prefWidth="260.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.NewCaskController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="12.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Klik op het kruisje om te annuleren." />
      <Label layoutX="12.0" layoutY="35.0" text="Prijs nieuw fust (in euro's zonder €):" />
      <TextField fx:id="price" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="56.0" promptText="Prijs" />
      <Label layoutX="12.0" layoutY="87.0" text="Volume (in milliliter):" />
      <TextField fx:id="volume" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="108.0" promptText="Volume" />
      <Label layoutX="12.0" layoutY="139.0" text="Type" />
      <TextField fx:id="type" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="160.0" promptText="Type" />
      <Button fx:id="confirm" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="201.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleConfirm" text="Bevestig" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**JavaFX of the original window**

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
  <items>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Huidig fust" />
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="58.0" text="Biersoort: " />
            <ProgressBar fx:id="caskProgress" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="35.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.5" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0" />
            <Label fx:id="beerTypeLabel" layoutX="81.0" layoutY="58.0" text="404 BIER NIET HIER" />
            <Button layoutX="12.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startNewCask" text="Nieuw fust" />
            <Button layoutX="113.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nieuwe gebruiker" />
            <Button layoutX="261.0" layoutY="82.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Statistieken" visible="false" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
</items>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
   </padding>
</SplitPane>
```

Comment: The JavaFX `Dialog` API is likely what you want. Check out this site for several great examples: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: @Zephyr this looks great, it probably is! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a popup it is better to use a [`Dialog`](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official) than a whole new JavaFX window. Credit to @Zephyr for bringing this to my attention.